# Step by step form keeps adding extra values to end result when user goes back

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with a jQuery form that I'm working on at the moment.

Whenever the user goes back to make a change in the form then it seems to add on the new values to the result rather than update them.

For example:

```
Capacity: 50-1000 people
Booking Date: 03/27/2012
Grade: 1 star
```

becomes

```
Capacity: 50-1000 people
Booking Date: 03/27/2012
Grade: 1 starCapacity: 50-1000 people
Booking Date: 03/27/2012
Grade: 1 star
```

How can I resolve this? You can find the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/36/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `.append()` to `.text()` or `.html()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use html() or text() instead:

```
$('#mdata').html('You said,<br/> capacity : '+FormData[0]+', date : '+FormData[1]+', grade : '+FormData[2]);
```